# Beautiful Soup in Python can not recover attribute in some wikipages

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, wikipedia, geo

It does get the coordinates for Link1, but the same code gets it for another country...why? (it worked well a year ago)

```
link1='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopia'
link2='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia'

identification = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'}
requestToServer2 = urllib2.Request(link2,headers=identification)
responseFromServerInHTML2 = urllib2.urlopen(requestToServer2)

subSoup = BS(responseFromServerInHTML2,'lxml')
coords=subSoup.find_all("span",{'class': 'geo'})[0].string

print coords
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two geo classes so findall gets both:

```
link2='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia'
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get(link2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
coords=soup.find_all("span",{'class': 'geo'})
print(coords)

[<span class="geo">60; 90</span>, <span class="geo">55.750; 37.617</span>]
```

If you want the second just access the second element:

```
print(coords[1].text)
55.750; 37.617
```

You can use the colspan to just find the second:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get(link2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print(soup.find("td",{'colspan': "2"})).find_next("span",{'class': 'geo'}).text
 55.750; 37.617
```